# How to read json data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Here the data I get as json from the server?

```
{id: 1, no: "CP101", pack: "PH"}
```

How can I read it using javascript?
when I use

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{id: 1, no: "CP101", pack: "PH"}');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.id + ", " + obj.no;
```

Gives me No output.

Comment: There are no quotes around the keys. There must be an error coming in console.

Comment: `{id: 1, no: "CP101", pack: "PH"}` is not JSON. How are you getting the data? Maybe it is already parsed for you.

Comment: So simple question you should search it first

Comment: javascript can read valid `JSON` [if do not put in ' OR "] , no need to parse actually

Comment: {id: 1, no: "CP101", pack: "PH"} this is already json object. don't parse and use it directly.

Comment: Data I get: [{"id":1,"no":"CP101","pack":"PH"}] After JSON.parse I get {id: 1, no: "CP101", pack: "PH"}

Comment: @ Pravin Tukadiya How to use?

Comment: this is an array of object so you can use like result[0].id.

Comment: see the answer of @Saeed.Ataee.

Comment: @PravinTukadiya: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: nice article @FelixKling thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should add some html sympol like this:

`document.getElementById('domId').innerHTML="<div>+"obj.id+obj.no+"</div>";`

because the innerHTML is content like string

Answer (score 0):

you must be well formatted your parsing data something like below-

var obj = JSON.parse('{"id": 1, "no": "CP101", "pack": "PH"}');

Answer (score 0):

Your Object is not stringified and you can not use `JSON.parse`.

```js
var obj = {
  id: 1,
  no: "CP101",
  pack: "PH"
};
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.id + ", " + obj.no;

console.log("Normal Object", obj, "Type of it is", typeof obj);

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log("Stringified Object", myJSON, "Type of it is", typeof myJSON);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

Comment: How to stringified my object?

Comment: @Rajnish: Why would you want to stringify it?

Comment: Read both links added to answer. A full description exists there.

Comment: Answer updated @Rajnish

Comment: Thank you for help I understand it

Comment: Your welcome, Good luck! @Rajnish